# sorts a linked list by using the Selection Sort

Tags: python, sorting, linked-list

I working to do sorts a linked list using the Selection Sort algorithm
I try to do it by using List BUT I could not.
so can any one help my to implement this by using Linked list?

This is my code so far

```
from list_linked import List
class Sorts:

    def selection_sort(a):


        current = a._front
        prv = None

        while current is not None:
            main_node = current
            prv = a._front
            current = current._next
            while current is not None:
                if main_node._value > current._value:
                    main_node = current
                else:
                    prv = prv._next
                current = current._next
            Sorts._swap(current, prv, main_node)

        return

    def _swap(self, first, prev, second):
        if first._next == second:
            second = self.swap_node(first)
        else:
            temp = first._next
            first._next = second._next
            second._next = temp
            prev._next = first
        return second, first

    def swap_node(self, node):
        second = node._next
        node._next = second._next
        second._next = node
        return second
```

The error I get for my finction:

```
Method 'selection_sort - sorts_linked' should have self as first 
 parameter
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *specific* problem you are facing.  Outline what you expect your code to do, and what it is actually doing. If you are receiving an error, include it in your question

Comment: @wnnmaw: I adit it

Comment: You are working with classes, and the message `should have self as first parameter` means that all the functions should have self as the first parameter `def selection_sort(self, a)`, etc.

Comment: There is no line beginning x = list_linked in the code above, so you have not shown us all the code